# Clarifying the ohmyzsh plugins

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I thought that the oh-my-zsh plugins allow you to use things like node and nvm without downloading them, by just including them in `~/.zshrc`. Turns out these plugins only offer autocomplete?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you might forget to add a proper plugin to your .zshrc.
adding the plugin will load and download nvm and set up node for you.

in a case nvm you only need `zsh-nvm` plugin
just add

```sh
# zsh-nvm plugin
export NVM_LAZY_LOAD=true

# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git zsh-nvm)
```

Comment: wait why is it not `plugins=(git nvm)`? i saw nvm in https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Plugins

Comment: [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm) is a Zsh plugin for installing, updating, and loading nvm. but [oh-my-zsh/nvm](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/nvm) plugin adds autocompletions for nvm

Comment: Oh i see! So the plugins here https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Plugins are just for autocomplete? How do I know whether an oh-my-zsh plugin I am looking at is for autocomplete or installing?

Comment: So I added the code above into my `~/.zshrc` but I get `[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'zsh-nvm' not found` when I open a new instance